# Restart problem after installing graphical card driver

Tags: 10.10, drivers, reboot, xorg, fglrx

My laptop is Lenovo T400, running Ubuntu 10.10.

1. **My problem:** I just run jockey-gtk and installed ATI/AMD
   proprietary FGLRX graphics driver.
   But after reboot, there is a short
   period of graphical "Ubuntu" and
   then instead of starting X-window it completely changed to
   command line to ask me to login. 
   Even after login and then issuing
   xinit, it still failed to start X.
2. **To solve this problem:** I followed [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1587508), where one
   person suggested to

   > you can simply write
   >
   > ```
   > sudo apt-get remove fglrx
   > ```
   >
   > This worked for me. If it doesn't
   >   work, then try
   >
   > ```
   > sudo apt-get remove xorg-driver-fglrx
   > ```
   >
   > and restart.

   I actually don't need the driver anyway, so I issued the first command after
   login under command line.

   But after
   reboot, the situation is even worse, and there is now even no
   command-line interface to ask me
   login, instead the screen is completely blank with just some
   ambient light in the background and
   Ubuntu is hanging there probably
   forever. So I have no chance to try the second command the person suggested.

I was wondering what I can do now to solve my problem? Thanks and regards!

Comment: An obvious thing you could do (and probably have done) would be: Did you try Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or F2 or F3) for a virtual console?

Comment: @luri: I did try that, nothing happened, still blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening when you after the removal the ATI drivers some bits are left in the system.

Could you please try following steps and get back here.

1. apt-get purge fglrx -modaliases fglrx amdcccle fglrx-kernel-source xorg-driver-fglrx xorg-driver-fglrx-dev
2. rm /etc/ati
3. rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf*
4. rm -rf /usr/share/ati
5. Reboot.